# How I can install .xap into my WP7.?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hello guys I am working on WP7 application and I wanted to show the progress to the client so how I have .xap file so once I can give this file to the client does it is directly install to  the WP7.?

if directly Install then how it is install.?

Thank you.!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the .xap on a windows phone is easy, assuming you are already set up for it.

You will need:

[Windows Phone Developer Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13890) and the [update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23854)

[Zune Software](http://www.zune.net/en-us/products/software/download/default.htm)

[Windows Live ID](https://accountservices.passport.net/ppnetworkhome.srf?vv=1350&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033)

[App Hub account](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/about/developer_registration_walkthrough) attached to your Live ID

Each of those can be picked up relatively quickly at those links. They are all free except the App Hub account which is $99 a year as of this post.

Once you have these the installation is trivial.

Plug in your phone, and the Zune software should open. In your Windows Phone Developer Tools, open Windows Phone Developer Registration. Simply input your Windows ID and password to register your device to your App Hub account (make sure your phone is on, unlocked, and connected to Zune). Then, go back to Windows Phone Developer Tools and open Application Deployment (again, make sure the phone is on, unlocked, and connected to Zune). Select Windows Phone 7 Device as your target, browse to the .xap, and hit "Deploy".

Answer (score 2):

In order to install a XAP your client will need a developer unlocked phone and Zune, plus the SDK tool to upload the XAP.

A much better option is to use the [Marketplace Beta Distribution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334585%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) mechanism, which is a fast way to distribute beta versions of your app to any user with a phone.